# Vue can't read property movies of undefined

Tags: vue.js, lodash, nuxt.js

So basically i want to input a keyword after that i will send an api request and after I receive the results I will push it to my movies(object) then loop through the results.

This is my code

```
<script>
import MovieCard from '~/components/MovieCard.vue'
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';
export default {

  name: 'Navbar',
   components:{
      MovieCard
    },
  data () {
    return {
        search: false,
        input: '',
        movies: {},
        
    }
  },
  methods:{
     searchMovies: _.debounce((e) =>  { 
        axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=123456789&query='+e.target.value)
       .then(response => {
        this.movies.push(response.data.results);
       })
      }, 2000)
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is from my form input

```
<input @keyup="searchMovies" v-model="input" type="text" class="w-full sm:h-20 h-16 dark2 border-0 md:pl-8 pl-4 md:pr-64 pr-24 focus:outline-none text-white inline-block">
```

This is the error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt3lw.png)

And this is the results of my API request
[Api results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPhWD.png)

Answer (score 0):

It means that it is unable to find `this`. You should rewrite your function like so:

```js
searchMovies() {
  _.debounce((e) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=123456789&query=" +
          e.target.value
      )
      .then((response) => {
        this.movies.push(response.data.results);
      });
  }, 2000);
}
```

And by the way, `this.movies` is an object so you cannot use `push`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your debounce callback to a function because  an arrow function wouldn't bind this to the vue instance.  In vuejs doc that writes:

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as
> created: () => console.log(this.a) or vm.$watch('a', newValue =>
> this.myMethod()). Since an arrow function doesn’t have a this, this
> will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through
> parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as Uncaught
> TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or Uncaught TypeError:
> this.myMethod is not a function.

```
data () {
    return {
        search: false,
        input: '',
        movies: [],
        
    }
  },
    methods:{
             searchMovies: _.debounce(function(e)  { 
                axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=123456789&query='+e.target.value)
               .then(response => {
                this.movies.push(response.data.results);
               })
              }, 2000)   }
```